# WCF RIA Services: overriding DomainService.AuthorizeChangeSet - who cares?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services

I am overriding the `AuthorizeChangeSet` method and return `false`. The change set is not applied to the data context as expected, but how is the client notiied about this authorization error? The returned `SubmitOperation` has no error, and I cannot find any information elsewhere inside.

(Still using the Nov 2009 beta with VS2008 and net3.5)

Comment: wow. I am a "tumbleweed" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no one cares. With reflector I finally found the place in the framework, where my `false` is being swallowed: `DomainService.AuthorizeChangeSet` is called by `DomainService.Submit`, which is still returning the outcome of `DomainService.AuthorizeChangeSet`. But see what the `ChangeSetProcessor.Process` is doing with it:

```
public static IEnumerable<ChangeSetEntry> Process(DomainService domainService, IEnumerable<ChangeSetEntry> changeSetEntries)
{
    ChangeSet changeSet = CreateChangeSet(changeSetEntries);
    domainService.Submit(changeSet);
    return GetSubmitResults(changeSet);
}
```

... nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest using the version that builds on .net 4.

Essentially what I'd expect to see is an error on the SubmitOperation that you can inspect on your Submit callback. The error should indicate there was an authorization failure.

Comment: In the meantime I migrated to VS2010 and the RC-Version but still no luck. The behavior is exactly the same.